# AJAX: Simple post not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I recently asked a question about javascript and php together and I got pointed into the direction of ajax.

I did some learning, and now I'm trying to do something really simple.

```
<input type="text" id="txt">
<input type="button" onclick="functionPost();" value="test123">
<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function functionPost() {
        var input = ('#txt').value;

        $.post('search.php', {postname: input},
        function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Basically, I get the value from the text input, I post it to the `search.php` page. If I echo something simple on this page, for example: `echo "hello";` the whole thing works. My div shows "hello".

But if I try to use the `$inputvalue = $_POST['postname'];`  on `search.php`, I get nothing at all, not even if I `echo $inputvalue;`.

I must be missing something small here.. I have no idea how ajax actually works, but I need this done.

Any ideas on why it won't get my posted value? I'm very inexperienced.

Thank you

Comment: It should be e.g: `var input = $('#txt').val();` or `var input =  document.getElementById('txt').value;`  On all HTML5 compilant browsers, you could use `var input = txt.value;` but don't, this is bad habit and calling for trouble

Comment: Look in your browser's console. Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `var input = ('#txt').value` to `var input = $('#txt').val()`.

Comment: That's what I did first, and I get a "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" using that

Comment: @Michiel Are you at least including jQuery? Is `$` referring to jQuery? We are agree, it is `$('#txt').val()` not just `('#txt').val()`?!

Comment: Wow, completely missed that dollar TWICE. Thank you both. I feel dumb

Comment: @Michiel Then replicate issue online, as a jsFiddle

Comment: @A.Wolff My bad.. Accepting the answer when it lets me

Comment: @Michiel Glad you've fixed it then ;)